# Backbone.js rendering delay?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Im new to backbone and there is one problem I cant figure out. I use backbone with require.js. When I want to render some view for the first time (when I reload page in browser) index.html shows up immediately but then it is hidden for about 2 seconds and then showed again with rendered templates. If I then navigate between views (without hitting refresh) it works smooth, but that initial render does something wrong. Here is my code:

View:

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone', 'text!../../../templates/home/HomeView.tpl'], 
function($, _, Backbone, HomeTemplate)
{
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend(
{
    events:{
    },

    render: function () 
    {
        var template = _.template(HomeTemplate);
        this.$el.html(template);

        return this;
    }

});

return HomeView;
});
```

Router:

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone'], 
function($, _, Backbone)
{ 
var container = $("#container");

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend(
{                       
    routes: 
    {
        "": "home"
    },

    home: function()
    {
        require(['views/home/HomeView'], 
        function(HomeView)
        {
            var Home = new HomeView({el: container});
            Home.render();
        });
    }


}); 


var initialize = function()
{
    var app_router = new AppRouter();


    Backbone.history.start();   
};

return { initialize: initialize };

});
```

I get no error in console. Is this behavior normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal.

RquireJs loads the dependencies via http requests and these requests do have timeouts. Additionally in browsers there is a limit for maximum parallel downloads. These delays can easily add up to 2 seconds at startup combined with network latency.

If You want to minimize this delay, minimize the files with r.js as mentioned in [RequireJS docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).

EDIT: If minify won't solve the problem, a browser profiling tool can help You.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Its strange since its all localhost, and it is kinda anoying for use, since you show user something and then go back to blank... How to avoid first blink?

Comment: I'm not convinced this would cause a 2 second delay on localhost with just 4 requests. I use the same set up and it's pretty much instant. 

The only difference is I precompile my backbone templates into JS functions rather than feeding in the raw text. This leads me to believe your inefficiency is in the initial template rendering. I'd try this with precompilation..

Comment: Have you tried using the chrome developer tools to get a better view on what's going on?